# XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efe, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efe

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-10

This AJAX code snippet works with all the modern browsers like Firefox, Chrome.But When I try to run this request on IE 10 I get the error mentioned above. What might be going wrong with Internet Explorer 10?

```
function requestBackupSetInfo() {
     var xmlhttp = getXMLObject();

     // Asynchronous function
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
             var tokens = xmlhttp.responseText.split("xml=");
             var xmlDataObject = createXmlDocument(tokens[1]);
         }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
     xmlhttp.send("COMMAND_ID=105");
 }
```

Comment: Why are you saying you are sending `application/xml` and then sending `"COMMAND_ID=105"` (which is clearly not XML)?

Comment: That was a mistake while posting, I have edited that part. Please Check

Comment: Did you try using XDomainRequest instead?